# Run DirectX proxy functions *after* the original functions than *before*?

Tags: c++, proxy, directx, directx-9, ogre3d

I have a proxy `D3D9.dll` and I noticed that my `DirectX::Present` is called before the one from the game.

Is it possible to reverse this (first the original functions, then my functions)? Some elements I draw are overriden by the game.

The game uses Ogre3D for rendering.

Note: I also want to do some "hacks" like freeze the camera and I noticed the following things:

Setting the camera position before the games' `DirectX::Present` function yields no results while setting the camera position after the games' `DirectX::Present` call results in the behaviour I want. (Tested with CheatEngine)

Answer (score 0):

usually you have in a proxy a structure like this:

```
HRESULT my_IDirect3DDevice9::Present(CONST RECT* pSourceRect,CONST RECT* pDestRect,HWND hDestWindowOverride,CONST RGNDATA* pDirtyRegion)
{
    return (m_pIDirect3DDevice9->Present( pSourceRect, pDestRect, hDestWindowOverride, pDirtyRegion));
}
```

to get the original function done first you would just need to do smth like:

```
HRESULT uMod_IDirect3DDevice9::Present(CONST RECT* pSourceRect,CONST RECT* pDestRect,HWND hDestWindowOverride,CONST RGNDATA* pDirtyRegion)
{
    HRESULT myresult = (m_pIDirect3DDevice9->Present( pSourceRect, pDestRect, hDestWindowOverride, pDirtyRegion));
    *** YOUR CODEWHATEVER ****
    return myresult;
}
```